# local variable stays uninitialized

Tags: php-7.1

The private array `$list_of_files` stays uninitialized. How can I update it from the while loop?

```
class listOfFiles {
private $list_of_files = [];

function __construct() {
  if ($handle = opendir(WEB_STORAGE_DIR)) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
      $this->list_of_files[$entry] = filesize(WEB_STORAGE_DIR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$entry);
    }

    closedir($handle);

    // Remove . and .. from the list
    unset($list_of_files['.']);
    unset($list_of_files['..']);
  }
}

function is_empty() {
  return empty($list_of_files);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$list_of_files` is referring to a variable, which is not the same as a property which would be `$this->list_of_files`.

Variables declared/referenced in a function are only available in that function (unless you use global - but this is generally considered 'evil' and should be avoided)

Properties are available from all methods in the class (unless they are static) and persist for the life of the object.

```
<?php
//lets show all error so we can see if anything else is going on..
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

class listOfFiles {
    private $list_of_files = [];

    function __construct() {
      if ($handle = opendir(WEB_STORAGE_DIR)) {

        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
          $this->list_of_files[$entry] = filesize(WEB_STORAGE_DIR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$entry);
        }

        closedir($handle);

        // Remove . and .. from the list
        unset($this->list_of_files['.']);
        unset($this->list_of_files['..']);
      }
    }

    function is_empty() {
      return empty($this->list_of_files);
    }
}
```

Is the issue that the directory doesn't exist? It would be better to check this before trying to open, and also allow for what to do when it does exist but you cant actually read it:

```
<?php
//lets show all error so we can see if anything else is going on..
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

class listOfFiles {
    private $list_of_files = [];

    function __construct() {
      if(!is_dir(WEB_STORAGE_DIR)){
        throw new Exception("Missing Web Storage Directory");
      }
      $handle = opendir(WEB_STORAGE_DIR);
      if (!$handle) {
        throw new Exception("Could not read Web Storage Directory");
      }
      else{

        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
          $this->list_of_files[$entry] = filesize(WEB_STORAGE_DIR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$entry);
        }

        closedir($handle);

        // Remove . and .. from the list
        unset($this->list_of_files['.']);
        unset($this->list_of_files['..']);
      }
    }

    function is_empty() {
      return empty($this->list_of_files);
    }
}
```

I have added `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` to the examples as this would make sure that you see any errors and may help debug your issue. More info on this here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Thanks, setting of `$this->list_of_files[$entry]` in the while loop fails, the private array declared as an property of the object stays uninitialized.

Comment: Are you sure that the path is valid - where does WEB_STORAGE_DIR come from? I have tested by using `__DIR__` instead which points to the directory of the file being executed and it works: see example code here http://pastebin.com/gAAzZSr6

Comment: You say it fails, in the while loop - do you get any errors or warnings? try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` to the top of your file to make sure you see errors - more info on this here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: WEB_STORAGE_DIR comes from an included config file. Your pastebin code works for me too,  so I must be doing wrong something else. Thanks for the error_reporting option. I will use it to dig deeper and find out what's wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ralph glad to hear; if this has answered your immediate issue would you be able to accept the answer (I get some internet points :) - and it helps others if they stumble across the same question)

Answer (score 0):

The access a property, you need to use `$this`, otherwise you are making a local variable. You do this at one place, but e.g. not here

```
  return empty($list_of_files);
```

As that variable is never set, this will always return the same thing.

```
  return empty($this->list_of_files);
```

The same goes for other references to that property, making the complete code (this is untested of course, as you didn't provide anything testable) look something like this

```
class listOfFiles {
  private $list_of_files = [];

  function __construct() {
    if ($handle = opendir(WEB_STORAGE_DIR)) {

      while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        $this->list_of_files[$entry] = filesize(WEB_STORAGE_DIR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$entry);
      }

      closedir($handle);

      // Remove . and .. from the list
      unset( $this->list_of_files['.']);
      unset( $this->list_of_files['..']);
    }
  }

  function is_empty() {
    return empty( $this->list_of_files);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see, I am missing `$this->...`in the return statement. I was unclear with my question; setting of `$this->list_of_files[$entry]` in the while loop fails, the private array declared as an property of the object stays uninitialized.

Comment: i have no clue what you mean, or how you test this. you should probably look into some basic debugging, and then tell exactly what goes wrong were, and what the error is. Anyway, fix your code with the properties first, id' say